# How can I simulate a change is in the power state with the ios emulator

Tags: ios, ios-simulator

I have some functionality that changes based on the device battery status, i.e. if it is charging/full else running on battery. I'm not trying to find out if the phone is in 'low battery status', only if it is plugged in or not.

Is there a way I can test this with the iOS simulator?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11105872/4475605

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Simulating low battery for iPhones](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11029519/simulating-low-battery-for-iphones)

Comment: I'm not trying to detect the low battery status, just wether it is plugged in or not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I did not achieve this with a simulator however I used network debugging with my iPhone and then I could plug and unplug the power without affecting my debug session.

`Cmd + Shift + 2` and then select `Connect via Network`.

[image: Device Settings]