# Simulating low battery in Safari on iOS simulator in 2020

Tags: ios, xcode, safari, ios-simulator, swift5

I'm trying to test and debug videos on a website that doesn't autoplay because of low battery states of some phones in Safari.

Is there any way of debugging this. I do not actually own an actual iPhone, so i would need to rely on simulators.

I understand the question has been asked before but way back in 2012, so im wondering if there has been any new methods of doing this.

[Simulating low battery for iPhones](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11029519/simulating-low-battery-for-iphones)

I have also used the followed settings in the cli to set the battery level in the simulator but im afraid its just a superficial change that doesnt actually simulate a device having low battery

```
xcrun simctl status_bar <device> override --time "9:41" --batteryState discharging --batteryLevel 9
```

Comment: Correct, that only changes the status bar display. The simulator reads your mac's battery level so currently the way to simulate this is to run your mac's battery down. Please file a feedback request for this feature, it sounds like there are some good use cases for it.